# mapping won't save and or return balances

Tags: solidity, remix, tokens, addresses

there is this mapping

`mapping(address => uint256) public balances;`

and these functions:

```
function hasEvenSubtrees(address _node) internal view returns (bool) {
        uint256 leftSubtrees = countSubtrees(nodes[_node].left);
        uint256 rightSubtrees = countSubtrees(nodes[_node].right);
        uint256 totalSubtrees = leftSubtrees + rightSubtrees + 1;
        return (totalSubtrees % 2 == 0);
    }

    function checkAndDistributeReward(address root) private {
        if (hasEvenSubtrees(root)) {
            uint256 rewardAmount = 2 ether;
            nodes[root].balance += rewardAmount;
            contractBalance -= rewardAmount;
            balances[root] += rewardAmount;
            emit RewardGiven(root, rewardAmount);
        }
    }
```

I call the checkAndDistributeReward(root) in a function called register so it has to save the balance in balances mapping. it won't. return value of balances(address) is always 0. i tried every way I knew and result is just the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the if statement is passed?

```
contract Test {
mapping(address => uint256) public balances;

function checkAndDistributeReward(address root) public {
    // if (hasEvenSubtrees(root)) {
        uint256 rewardAmount = 2 ether;
        // nodes[root].balance += rewardAmount;
        // contractBalance -= rewardAmount;
        balances[root] += rewardAmount;
        // emit RewardGiven(root, rewardAmount);
    // }
}
```

}

Without the if (obviously) works for me. If you wrote unit tests you can try a hardhat test coverage to see if "if" is passed or not.